# Modify Strings in a ELF (Executable and Linking Format) that are stored in the .rodata

Tags: binary-analysis, elf, binary, c#, binary-editing

I have 2 ELF files here, each containing strings in the ".rodata" for an translation that I want to modify.
The first ELF "(binary1)" I have already successfully modified from Chinese to German.
The second ELF "(binary2)" has a slightly different structure.
In my first ELF file "(binary1)", which I successfully modified, the pointers for the respective strings were in the ".data.rel.ro" part.
So with a short C# code I could output the strings.

```
    static int start_data_rel_ro = 0x1708; 
    static int end_data_rel_ro = 0x1A3CF; 


    static void binToConsole(string inputFile)
    {
        var data = getData(inputFile);
        
        for (int i = start_data_rel_ro; i < end_data_rel_ro;)
        {
                var line = "";

                    var addr = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[] { data[i], data[i + 1], data[i + 2], data[i + 3],0,0,0,0 },0);
                        i += 4;                        
                    List<byte> textData = new List<byte>();
                    do
                    {
                        textData.Add(data[addr] == 10 ? ((byte)0x7C) : data[addr]);
                        addr++;
                    } while (data[addr] != 0);
                    line = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(textData.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine(line);
        }          
    }
  
    static byte[] getData(string path)
    {
        byte[] data;

        using (var file = File.OpenRead(path))
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.CopyTo(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();                
        }

        return data;
    }
```

For the "(binary1)" I already have a finished program which stores the strings in a CSV and afterwards inserts the CSV back into the "(binary1)" and patches the pointers. So I can make a string longer if I make a string shorter somewhere else.

Here is an excerpt of my previous file, which I have processed successfully

The **.rodata** contains all strings:
[image: rodata_example]

The **.data.rel.ro** contains all pointers to the strings:
[image: data.rel.ro_example]

but the new file "(binary2)" I want to edit now looks a bit different.

**.rodata**
[image: rodata]

**.data.rel.ro**
[image: data.rel.ro]

My C# code can't work in the second ELF, because it's a bit different. Unfortunately I don't know what to do. Maybe someone has an approach for me, so I can write a new little tool.

Here is a download link to the "(binary2)": https://drive.google.com/file/d/12vr-zcTnC3TzCIuvZ9Yt19lbb6dkEFdl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you limited to C#? Otherwise you could have a look at [elfutils](https://sourceware.org/elfutils/) for writing a tool that understands ELF and can manipulate it. If you're tied to C#, however, you may have to generate a C# binding first.

Comment: @0xC0000022L No, I‘m not limited to C#. It was relatively obvious to me in C# to modify the first ELF. Do you have some experience with this and could give me an approach so that I don‘t have to search many days?

Comment: I can't personally vouch for either of these, but they may be useful. https://github.com/yalue/elf32_string_replace  
https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1843/what-are-the-available-libraries-to-statically-modify-elf-executables